# How to print id specific data?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to print dishes relevant to my restaurants. Each dish is assigned a `restaurant_id`.

Each restaurant is assigned an `ID`.

restaurant migration

```
Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

dish migration

```
Schema::create('dishes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('restaurant_id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

restaurant seeder

```
DB::table('restaurants')->insert([
        'name' => 'Bellos Pizzeria',
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    ]);

    DB::table('restaurants')->insert([
        'name' => 'McDonalds',
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    ]);

    DB::table('restaurants')->insert([
        'name' => 'Ericos',
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    ]);
```

dish seeder

```
    DB::table('dishes')->insert([
        'name' => 'Butter Chicken',
        'price' => '12',
        'restaurant_id' => 1,
        'image' => 'dishes_images/default.png',
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    ]);

    DB::table('dishes')->insert([
        'name' => 'Hamburger',
        'price' => '10',
        'restaurant_id' => 2,
        'image' => 'dishes_images/default.png',
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    ]);
```

html on individual restaurant view

```
@section('content')
    <h1> {{$restaurant->name}} </h1>

    <a href="/assignment2/public/restaurant"> back </a>
@endsection
```

I'm trying to print the dishes relevant to the restaurants. For example, 'Butter Chicken' (`id=1`) to be listed on restaurant 'Bellos Pizzeria' (`id=1`).

Comment: You should make  relationship first, then you can access your desire data

Comment: Have you set up an eloquent relationship between the restaurant and the dishes?

Comment: You have to implement relationship https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Restaurant` model write the relationship code. Seeing your question above I understand that the relationship is an One-to-many relationship. In that case write this in restaurant model.

**Restaurant.php**

```
public function dishes(){
    return $this->hasMany(Dish::class);
    //it define the relation type between Restaurant and Dish model
}
```

**blade file**

```
<h1> {{$restaurant->name}} </h1>

<ul>
    @foreach($restaurant->dishes as $dish)
        <li>{{ $dish->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

`$restaurant->dishes` will return an array/collection of all related dishes associated with the restaurant. Use `@foreach` to display all dishes.

User your own `Html`, I used `ul` `li` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a laravel relationship. Like

Create `Restaurants` and `Dishes` Model.

In Your Restaurants Model:

```
class Restaurants extends Model
{
    function dishes() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Dishes');
    }
}
```

In your Dish Model

```
class Dishes extends Model
{
    function restaurants() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Restaurants');
    }
}
```